# Query not returning values

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sqlserver

I have the written the query below to return two values. I have also check the DE to ensure that it has the correct data types. Unfornately, the query is not returning any values:

```
SELECT
M.EmailAddress  EmailAddress 
,M.PersonHasOptedOutOfEmail PersonHasOptedOutOfEmail

FROM

MasterSubscriberDE M

JOIN  [4DaySend] F

ON M.SubscriberKey = F.SubscriberKey

WHERE 

PersonHasOptedOutOfEmail = 'False'
```

Here is a screenshot of the Data Extension:

[image]

I know its a very basic query but I seem to be missing a trick and stumped by this. Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: If you run it in an automation does it get an error or run successfully?

Comment: And why are you not referencing the DE to which you are joining?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boolean values can be represented with `1` or `0`.  Assuming the there's not always going to be a match in `4DaySend`, I'd do something like this:

```
SELECT
M.EmailAddress  EmailAddress 
, M.PersonHasOptedOutOfEmail PersonHasOptedOutOfEmail
FROM MasterSubscriberDE M
LEFT JOIN  [4DaySend] F ON (M.SubscriberKey = F.SubscriberKey)
WHERE m.PersonHasOptedOutOfEmail = 0
```